# virtual function default arguments behaviour

Tags: c++

I have a strange situation over the following code. Please help me to get it clarified.

```
class B
{
       public:
            B();
            virtual void print(int data=10)
            {
                  cout << endl << "B--data=" << data;
            }
};
class D:public B
{
       public:
            D();
            void print(int data=20)
            {
                  cout << endl << "D--data=" << data;
            }
};

int main()
{
     B *bp = new D();
     bp->print();
return 0;
}
```

Regarding the output I expected

```
[ D--data=20 ]
```

But in practical it is

```
[ D--data=10 ]
```

Please help. It may seem obvious for you but I am not aware of the internal mechanism.

Comment: If an answer solves your problem (or makes you understand it), please accept it, using the green tick on the left of the answer.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Default arguments are entirely compile-time feature. I.e. the substitution of default arguments in place of missing arguments is performed at compile time. For this reason, obviously, there's no way default argument selection for member functions can depend on the *dynamic* (i.e. run-time) type of the object. It always depends on *static* (i.e. compile-time) type of the object.

The call you wrote in your code sample is immediately interpreted by the compiler as `bp->print(10)` regardless of anything else.

Comment: Thanks Andrey for clearing my doubt. I did not think in this direction. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 32):

The standard says (8.3.6.10):

> A virtual function call (10.3) uses
>   the default arguments in the
>   declaration of the virtual function
>   determined by the static type of the
>   pointer or reference denoting the
>   object. An overriding function in a
>   derived class does not acquire default
>   arguments from the function it
>   overrides.

This means, since you are calling `print` through a pointer of type `B`, it uses the default argument of `B::print`.

Comment: Fundoo answer but helps to understand. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Generally, those default arguments are used that are visible at a certain scope. You can do (but shouldn't) funky things:

```
#include <iostream>
void frob (int x) {
    std::cout << "frob(" << x << ")\n";
}

void frob (int = 0);
int main () {
    frob();                     // using 0
    {
        void frob (int x=5) ;
        frob();                 // using 5
    }
    {
        void frob (int x=-5) ;
        frob();                 // using -5
    }
}
```

In your case, the base class signature is visible. In order to use the derived default arguments, you must explicitly call that function through a pointer to your derived class, either by declaring it that way, or by casting it rightly.

Answer (score 1):

Default argument value is passed on behalf of the caller. From the caller viewpoint it works with class B (not D), so it passes 10 (as for class B)

Answer (score 0):

The dynamic binding is using vpointer and vtable. However, the dynamic binding only applies to function pointer. There is no mechanism to dynamic bind argument.

Thus, the default argument is determined statically at compiler time. In this case, it is statically determined by bp type, which is a pointer to Base class. Thus data = 10 is passed as function argument, while the function pointer is pointing to Derived class member function: D::print. Essentially, it calls D::print(10).

The following code snippet and the resulting outputs clearly demonstrate the point: even though it calls the Derived call member function Derived::resize(int), it passes the Base class default argument: size=0.

virtual void Derived::resize(int) size 0

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

#define pr_dbgc(fmt,args...) \
    printf("%d %s " fmt "\n",__LINE__,__PRETTY_FUNCTION__, ##args);

class Base {
   public:
       virtual void resize(int size=0){
           pr_dbgc("size %d",size);
       }
};

class Derived : public Base {
   public:
       void resize(int size=3){
           pr_dbgc("size %d",size);
       }
};

int main()
{   
    Base * base_p = new Base;
    Derived * derived_p = new Derived;

    base_p->resize();           /* calling base member function   
                                   resize with default
                                   argument value --- size 0 */
    derived_p->resize();        /* calling derived member      
                                   function resize with default 
                                   argument default --- size 3 */

    base_p = derived_p;         /* dynamic binding using vpointer 
                                   and vtable */
                                /* however, this dynamic binding only
                                   applied to function pointer. 
                                   There is no mechanism to dynamic 
                                   binding argument. */
                                /* So, the default argument is determined
                                   statically by base_p type,
                                   which is pointer to base class. Thus
                                   size = 0 is passed as function 
                                   argument */

    base_p->resize();           /* polymorphism: calling derived class   
                                   member function 
                                   however with base member function  
                                   default value 0 --- size 0 */

     return 0;
}


 #if 0
 The following shows the outputs:
 17 virtual void Base::resize(int) size 0
 24 virtual void Derived::resize(int) size 3
 24 virtual void Derived::resize(int) size 0
 #endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what happens when you declare a function with a default argument like this is that you're (implicitly) declaring and defining an inline overload with one fewer argument that just calls the full function with that argument value.  The thing is, this extra overloaded function is *not* virtual, even if the function is.  So the function you've defined in B is equivalent to:

```
        virtual void print(int data)
        {
              cout << endl << "B--data=" << data;
        }
        void print() { print(10); }
```

what this means is that when you call `print()` (with no argument) the function you get is based on the static type (B in the case you find confusing).  That then calls `print(int)` which is virtual, so uses the dynamic type.

If you want this default argument to be virtual, you need to explicitly define the overloaded function (as virtual) to make it work.

Answer (score -2):

your variable is of type B, so the function of B will be called. To call D, you have to either declare your variable as D, or cast to D.

Comment: Since the `print` member function is declared virtual, calling through a base class pointer will call the derived version of the member function, not the base version.