# Virtual function with default argument, weird output

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, virtual-functions, default-arguments

The output of this code is `15` and I really don't know why. I think that it uses `x=5` in the `foo` function but I don't know why. Can anyone help me ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


struct A
{
    virtual int foo(int x = 5)
    {
        return x*2;
    }
};

struct B : public A
{
    int foo(int x = 10)
    {
        return x*3;
    }
};



int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  A* a = new B;
  cout << a->foo();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [virtual function default arguments behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6464404/virtual-function-default-arguments-behaviour)

Answer (score 6):

> I think that it uses `x=5` in the `foo` function but I don't know why.

Yes, the default argument from the base class `A`'s declaration (i.e. `5`) is used here, because you're calling `foo()` on an object with static type `A*`. The [default arguments](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_arguments) are decided based on the static type, other than the dynamic type.

The standard has a clear explanation about this, [$8.3.6/10 Default arguments
[dcl.fct.default]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.default#10):

(emphasis mine)

> A virtual function call ([[class.virtual]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.virtual)) uses the default arguments
>   in the declaration of the virtual function determined by the **static
>   type of the pointer or reference denoting the object**. An overriding
>   function in a derived class does not acquire default arguments from
>   the function it overrides. [ Example:
>
> ```
> struct A {
>   virtual void f(int a = 7);
> };
> struct B : public A {
>   void f(int a);
> };
> void m() {
>   B* pb = new B;
>   A* pa = pb;
>   pa->f();          // OK, calls pa->B::f(7)
>   pb->f();          // error: wrong number of arguments for B::f()
> }
> ```
>
> — end example ]

Answer (score 3):

There are two parts to this invocation:

- **Deciding what value to pass to `x`** - this is the default parameter of `A::foo`, i.e. 5, because that is the *static* type of `a`, i.e. the type known at compile time. If you think about it, this is the only choice the compiler has, because it must not make assumptions about the type assigned to `a`.
- **Deciding which class receives the call** - this is `B::foo`, because the dynamic type of the object pointed to by `a` is `struct B`.

Hence you get 3*5 as your output.